# Deploying Asp.Net MVC core application on Godaddy Linux Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, web-hosting

Is there any option to make Asp.net Mvc core application work in godaddy or other providers linux hosting?

Comment: sure, [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21) -> move over FTP/SFTP -> reverse-proxy by NGINX

Comment: Will this work on Linux shared hosting?

Comment: yes. All you need is to install [.net core runtime](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download)

Comment: @kurkula If your hosting provider support .net core, then it is working. If not, yeah is not working. You better check it wiht them first. Or you can use asphostportal, .net core working perfectly on their server.